# sql query to copy a row using substring , md5, base convert, and concat

Tags: mysql

I have two BIGINT columns called `first_half` and `second_half` and an empty column called `new_column`.

I would like the `new column` to be a BIGINT column that is the first 16 characters of the base converted md5 (from base 16 to base 10) of the concatenated string versions of those `first_half` and `second_half` bigints.

I realize that's a lot to say in one sentence.

Here is the sql query that I'd like to run:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET new_column = SUBSTRING(CONV(MD5(CONCAT(CONVERT(first_half, VARCHAR(50)), CONVERT(second_half, VARCHAR(50)))), 16, 10), 0, 16);
```

The problem with this is, I either get a value of `0` for all columns, and identical value for all columns like `1234567890123456` (should be different values for all columns, because the `second_half` is mostly unique), or (at this point) a syntax error that I can't figure out.

Can anyone help me out with this? I feel like this shouldn't be difficult, but I'm really tripping over it today.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I get all the same values in `new_column` even though all of the `second_half` entries are different